# FadeInImage widget "fades in" when i pop back to a previous screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two screens. Screen one has a FadeInImage widget that shows a nice fade in animation when i launch my app. My issue now is when i navigate to screen two and pop back this fading in repeats itself. . I have tried using a stateful widget with automatickeepalive mixin but it doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated

```
class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        primary: false,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6, right: 6),
        itemCount: 4,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: aspectRatio ?? 180 / 304,
          crossAxisSpacing: 0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo()),


 )
                    },
                    child: 
                                Container(
                                  height: 191,
                                  width: 180,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                                      child: FadeInImage(
                                        placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                                'https://i.pravatar.cc/300'),
                                        imageErrorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                            Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
                                          return Icon(Icons.error);
                                        },
                                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                        height: 300,
                                        width: 270,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),)});}}


class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some code so we can see what the problem might be.

Comment: @MSpeed added some reproducible code

Comment: What is `kTransparentImage`?

Comment: A transparent image from the transparent_image package.